# HTML - If flash not installed, show a div or image

Tags: html, flash

Hey Guys, I asked a question last night and got an answer almost instantly. LOVE stack overflow!.

I am working on the same site and the other day I was on a computer and the uploader script was not working (uploadify), I was frustrated and looked through the code and everything was fine, worked on all other computers, then I decided to check if flash was installed and it wasnt.

Is there any way to check if the user has flash, and if they dont somehow say that on the page? I know for Javascript there is a  tag, but is there something I can use for Flash?

Thanks a ton guys!!

Comment: Normally your flash embedding script will take care of this. Which one are you using - Adobe's own? swfobject? something else?

Comment: swf object (http://www.uploadify.com/) is the uploader im using, its amazing, just want to add some support for non flash users.

Comment: No, uploadify doesn't use swfobject. The actual embedding is done by [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/) code which is included minified at the top of jquery.uploadify.js. It's that code you'll need to enhance.

Answer (score 7):

is it acceptable to use a bit of javascript to achieve this? You can use the [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

Example from [learnswfobject.com](http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("mymovie.swf", "flashcontent", "550px", "400px", "9");
</script>
<body>
    <div id="flashcontent">
      Fallback or 'alternate' content goes here.
      This content will be replaced by the SWF
      after SWFObject embeds it.
    </div>
</body>
```